# How to scroll an element using selenium-webdriver with ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a div there is scroll type element like: mobile calendar scrolling.

So how can i perform it.

I have tried

```
page.driver.browser.action.click_and_hold(first(".dwww .dww .dw-ul .dw-i"))
page.driver.browser.mouse.down
```

but could not scroll and element.

page html is:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td><div class="dwwl dwrc dwwl0"><div class="dwl">Month</div><div class="dwww"><div style="height:120px;min-width:70px;" class="dww"><div class="dw-ul" style="transition: all 0s ease-out 0s ; transform: translate3d(0px, -160px, 0px);"><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="0" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">01</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">02</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="2" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">03</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="3" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">04</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="4" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">05</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="5" class="dw-li dw-sel dw-v"><div class="dw-i">06</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="6" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">07</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="7" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">08</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="8" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">09</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="9" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">10</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="10" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">11</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="11" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">12</div></div></div></div><div class="dwwol"></div></div><div class="dwwo"></div></div><div class="dwwol"></div></div></td><td><div class="dwwl dwrc dwwl1"><div class="dwl">Day</div><div class="dwww"><div style="height:120px;min-width:70px;" class="dww"><div class="dw-ul" style="transition: all 0s ease-out 0s ; transform: translate3d(0px, -640px, 0px);"><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">01</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="2" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">02</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="3" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">03</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="4" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">04</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="5" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">05</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="6" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">06</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="7" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">07</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="8" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">08</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="9" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">09</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="10" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">10</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="11" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">11</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="12" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">12</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="13" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">13</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="14" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">14</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="15" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">15</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="16" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">16</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="17" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">17</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="18" class="dw-li dw-sel dw-v"><div class="dw-i">18</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="19" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">19</div></div></div><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="20" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">20</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="21" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">21</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="22" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">22</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="23" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">23</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="24" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">24</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="25" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">25</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="26" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">26</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="27" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">27</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="28" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">28</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="29" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">29</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="30" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">30</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="31" class="dw-li dw-h"><div class="dw-i">31</div></div></div></div><div class="dwwol"></div></div><div class="dwwo"></div></div><div class="dwwol"></div></div></td><td><div class="dwwl dwrc dwwl2"><div class="dwl">Year</div><div class="dwww"><div style="height:120px;min-width:70px;" class="dww"><div class="dw-ul" style="transition: all 0s ease-out 0s ; transform: translate3d(0px, -3120px, 0px);"><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1913" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">13</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1914" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">14</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1915" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">15</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1916" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">16</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1917" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">17</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1918" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">18</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1919" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">19</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1920" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">20</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1921" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">21</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1922" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">22</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1923" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">23</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1924" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">24</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1925" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">25</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1926" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">26</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1927" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">27</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1928" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">28</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1929" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">29</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1930" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">30</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1931" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">31</div></div></div><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1932" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">32</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1933" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">33</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1934" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">34</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1935" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">35</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1936" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">36</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1937" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">37</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1938" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">38</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1939" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">39</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1940" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">40</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1941" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">41</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1942" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">42</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1943" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">43</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1944" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">44</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1945" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">45</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1946" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">46</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1947" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">47</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1948" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">48</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1949" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">49</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1950" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">50</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1951" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">51</div></div></div><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1952" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">52</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1953" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">53</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1954" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">54</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1955" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">55</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1956" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">56</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1957" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">57</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1958" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">58</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1959" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">59</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1960" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">60</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1961" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">61</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1962" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">62</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1963" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">63</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1964" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">64</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1965" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">65</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1966" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">66</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1967" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">67</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1968" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">68</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1969" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">69</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1970" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">70</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1971" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">71</div></div></div><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1972" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">72</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1973" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">73</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1974" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">74</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1975" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">75</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1976" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">76</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1977" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">77</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1978" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">78</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1979" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">79</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1980" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">80</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1981" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">81</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1982" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">82</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1983" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">83</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1984" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">84</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1985" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">85</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1986" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">86</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1987" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">87</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1988" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">88</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1989" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">89</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1990" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">90</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1991" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">91</div></div></div><div class="dw-bf"><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1992" class="dw-li dw-v dw-sel"><div class="dw-i">92</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1993" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">93</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1994" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">94</div></div><div style="height:40px;line-height:40px;" data-val="1995" class="dw-li dw-v"><div class="dw-i">95</div></div></div></div><div class="dwwol"></div></div><div class="dwwo"></div></div><div class="dwwol"></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look around [`Class: Selenium::WebDriver::ActionBuilder`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html). I didn't see your html code. But I used Wikipedia official page to illustrate the scrolling functionality.The below code will work. You will see that page will be auto scrolled down to the *Wiktionary*.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://www.wikipedia.org/"

el = driver.find_elements(:css, "div.otherprojects-item > div > a")
p el[1].text #=> "Wiktionary"
driver.action.move_to(el[1]).perform
```

Try the above and let me know. I didn't test,looking for your feedback.

Comment: @user2455048 so any error you encountered or what? also please metntion your **ruby** and **selenium-webdriver** version.

Comment: I doesn't get any error. but this is not working. I am using jruby-1.7.3 and selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)

Comment: @user2455048 when you run the code, you should see you will be auto scrolled to the below page to the element *Wiktionary*. Does it not happen? So what are you seeing when you run the code?

Comment: For those wanting the answer to this in Java, the class you are looking for is called Actions. http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html